# How to use sed to replace multiple strings with the same pattern in a file

Tags: sed, regular-expression, rename

I am trying to use the sed command to modify a file.   The original file has 5 chromosomes, which named "1 CHROMOSOME", "2 CHROMOSOME", "3 CHROMOSOME", "4 CHROMOSOME", "5 CHROMOSOME" respectively.   Now I want to rename these five chromosomes to chr1, chr2, chr3, chr4, chr5 instead.   I try with sed command to do this.  I know I could do one at a time, but how could I rename all five once.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a *capture group* for the digit and a *backreference* to resubstitute it:

```
sed 's/\([12345]\) CHROMOSOME/chr\1/g' file
```

See for example [Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)